# getchar, Linux и поток-ввод. Что происходит когда ввод заканчивается

Tags: linux, c, ввод, символы

Вeчep дoбрый, я надеюсь...

Предистория:

Есть программа, в которую текст должен подаваться командой (ОС Linux):

> ./lb4 < testB.txt

В ней я использовал считывание:

```
while (scanf("%c", &tmpchar) > 0){
    switch (tmpchar){
       бла-бла-бла
    }
}
```

И, когда ввод заканчивался, scanf становился -1 и все хорошо...

НО! Т.к. scanf **очень** тугадум, особенно, когда речь идет о 2,5 Gb текста...

Программа однопоточная (лаба) - поэтому поидее я могу использовать *getchar_unlocked*...

Хотелось бы узнать, как он себя ведет в подобных случаях, и как отловить конец ввода?

Comment: [man getchar](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) читали?

Comment: нет, я по английски не очень...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сам проверил - вернет **EOF**

...

...

...

Comment: Точно. Поэтому читать надо  обязательно в переменную **типа int** / Вот так: **`int c; ... c = getchar(); if (c == EOF) ...`**  (или можно так:  `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }`)